# session_destroy() executes earlier than I need

Tags: php, session

So i am having code like this:

```
$_SESSION['message'] = "Some Message";
$MSG = $_SESSION['message'];
header('location: ../Pages/Error.php');
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$MSG');</script>"; //It has text here
die(); //i set this only for testing purpose
session_destroy();
die();
```

As you can see up there i have 2 `die()` - first is for this test purpose.

So when code is WITH that first `die()` and `echo()` my `../Pages/Error.php` which uses `$_SESSION['message']` display that message normally since inside `Error.php` file and `alert`(which is also for testing purpose) but when i remove those two for some reason `sesion_destroy();` runs faster than `header()` function and id destroys my `$_SESSION['message']` so my `Error.php` shows empty message.

Code without testing parts:

```
$_SESSION['message'] = "Some Message";
$MSG = $_SESSION['message'];
header('location: ../Pages/Error.php');
session_destroy();
die();
```

Could someone explain me why this happens?

Comment: `header('location: ../Pages/Error.php') & die('<script>alert("'.$_SESSION['message'].'");</script>');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what happens (times are just for example). Notice that this ISN'T automatically what might happen.

```
1 $_SESSION['message'] = "Some Message";
2 $MSG = $_SESSION['message'];
3 header('location: ../Pages/Error.php');
4 echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$MSG');</script>"; //It has text here
5 You do not have buffering, so header and echo go out to the browser.
6 session_destroy();
8           The browser receives the Location header
7 The server destroys the session file.
9           The browser requests the page
10          The server receives the request
11          The server tries to load the session file. Duh! It's not there!
```

It could go this slightly different other way:

```
4 echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$MSG');</script>"; //It has text here
5 You have buffering, so nothing gets output.
6 session_destroy();
7 The server destroys the session file.
8 The scripts exits, the buffer is flushed

9           The browser receives the Location header
10           The browser requests the page
11          The server receives the request
12          The server tries to load the session file. Duh! It's not there!
```

It could go (on some systems) in a more disastrous way, with the session_destroy and the session_start of the second script running into each other so that the second script reads a damaged session and chokes (this should not happen thanks to locking; but locking has its own drawbacks, see below).

A more interesting thing could happen if your first script does not die, but issues a `Location` header and keeps working. Data in the session will not be stored until the script terminates, so if the second script gets launched, it will find a non-updated session. But if you activate buffering, the Location will be sent *at the end*, and the second script will work. So the buffering apparently "solves" what is really a race problem.

## Session impact on performances

An even more interesting thing happens on those systems where read/write access to the session file is arbitrated through locking (as it should, since "race conditions" are BAD, as seen above), and you have transparent sessions, so a lot of requests to your framework - even those that need save no session data, maybe needn't even read it - end up piling up one behind the other because they can't run in parallel as long as they're semaphorized by the session file FS lock.

You can easily diagnose this behaviour using Chrome or Firefox Web Tools, seeing as e.g. AJAX calls start asynchronously, but the actual data delivery is serialized:

```
-----SXXXXXXXX----------
--------SwwwwwwwwwXXX---
-----SwwwwwXXXXX--------
-------SwwwwwXXXXX------
--------SwwwwwwXXX------
     |<------------>|
```

In that case, adding "[session_write_close()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php)" immediately after `session_start()`, or anyway as soon as possible (in the class constructor for some frameworks) for those files that might need to read the session, *but do not change it*, will appear to magically speed up your application (the same happens removing any unneeded session_start()'s, but the framework might make this complex to achieve):

```
-----SXXXXXXXX---
--------SwwXXX---
-----SwwXXXXX----
-------SwXXXXX---
--------SwXXX----
     |<----->| "perceived" user time goes down a good 40%
```

Answer (score 2):

This happens because your browser is redirecting to the new page **before** THIS script (the one you have shown above) actually writes the session data to the storage. The session-data is kept in-memory until the script finishes or until you call [session_write_close()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php) manually.

This means to get your example working you would have to write the session data before outputting the redirect header, like so:

```
$_SESSION['message'] = "Some Message";
$MSG = $_SESSION['message'];
session_write_close();
header('location: ../Pages/Error.php');
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$MSG');</script>"; //It has text here
die(); //i set this only for testing purpose
session_destroy();
die();
```

This also means that your session is **not** "faster destroyed than you are redirected", as you intially suspected.

Comment: I do not get it. I edited my question and posted it without lines that i do for testing. Could you look at that please.

Comment: @AleksaRistic The same reasoning applies. If you just redirect the browser before writing the session data to the storage, your new request will already start when the handling of this request has not been finished yet, and therefore no session data was written at that point.

Comment: But in other parts of my code i am not using `session_write_close();` anywhere and it works somehow.

Comment: @AleksaRistic Well, this is pretty much a [race condition issue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition). Some times you may have luck, others you might not. However, it does have nothing to do with destroying your session imho.